# Trouble with RequireJS on Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, requirejs

I'm trying to use RequireJS to load server side modules in my node project based on the instructions here:  http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

My boot file looks like this:

```
var requirejs = require( "requirejs" );

requirejs.config({ nodeRequire: require });

requirejs([ "app" ], function( app ) {

  app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log( "We be shuffling..." );
  });

});
```

Then, I have an app file like so...

```
requirejs([

    "express"

  ], function ( express ) {

  var app = express();

  app.configure( "development", function(){
    app.use( express.errorHandler() );
  });

  return app;

});
```

...however this just spills out a bunch of errors:

> timers.js:103
>               if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
>                                                                         ^ TypeError: Cannot call method 'listen' of undefined
>       at /home/ssp/boot.js:13:7
>       at Object.context.execCb (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1729:33)
>       at Object.Module.check (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:969:51)
>       at Object.Module.enable (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1239:22)
>       at Object.Module.init (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:882:26)
>       at Object.context.makeRequire.mixin.isBrowser [as _onTimeout] (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1505:36)
>       at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19) root@nodeapp:/home/ssp# node boot
>
> timers.js:103
>               if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
>                                                                         ^ TypeError: Cannot call method 'listen' of undefined
>       at /home/ssp/boot.js:13:7
>       at Object.context.execCb (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1729:33)
>       at Object.Module.check (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:969:51)
>       at Object.Module.enable (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1239:22)
>       at Object.Module.init (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:882:26)
>       at Object.context.makeRequire.mixin.isBrowser [as _onTimeout] (/home/ssp/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1505:36)
>       at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)

Does anyone have any suggestions what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to use require with express, why not use the automatic setup script? For instructions on how to set up express using npm, see http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable Basically, you just use express on the command line. Require is included in the setup.

Comment: requirejs is great on the client side and for consistency i would like to do the same on the server side. RequireJS is commonly used for this purpose, so I'd like to figure out what I'm doing wrong, not use a workaround.

Comment: This is for the server side.

Comment: Yup, RequireJS on the server side.  If I can get it working, I think it is a nicer way of modularizing code than the default commonJS patterns node uses.

Comment: Hey! That's what I am saying. You want to use RequireJS on the server side for your Express app. The express command line executable will set up an app for you using RequireJS. You will then be able to call require on any other modules you have installed via npm. The app.js file that the express executable creates contains the line var express = require('express');

Comment: I think there is some confusion.  Having express generate a site skeleton doesn't install requirejs (http://requirejs.org/) as far as I know, which is a different module loader.  (requirejs != require)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define() your "module" app instead use requirejs(), because you need to declare your module first.

Add `var define = require("amdefine")` to your bootfile.

and in your app file :

```
define(["express" ], 
   function ( express ) {
     var app = express();
     app.configure( "development", function(){
     app.use( express.errorHandler() );
   }); 
   return app; 
});
```